# Ошибка доступа к переменным поля protected

Tags: c++

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить данную проблему!
В программе есть класс employee с полем protected. В функции zarplata я пытаюсь изменить данные переменных этого поля через указатель (объект класса employee, на который указывает указатель k, был создан заранее), но программа выдаёт ошибку доступа к полю. См. код ниже.

```
class employee//сотрудник
{
protected:
    string name;
    string surname;
    string patronymic;
    double salary = 0;
};

void zarplata(employees *k)
    {
        if (k->position == "Бухгалтер") k->j.salary = standart * stavka_accountant;
        if (k->position == "Секретарь") k->j.salary = standart * stavka_secretary;
        if (k->position == "Сисадмин") k->j.salary = standart * stavka_administrator;
        if (k->position == "Директор") k->j.salary = standart * stavka_director;
        return;
    }
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: т.е. вы хотите ломать концепцию ООП? почему просто `protected` на `public` тогда просто не заменить?

Comment: К protected полю вы можете обращаться только из данного класса и наследника. `zarplata` не член класса `employee`Ю и не член его наследника. Все правильно.

Comment: @Zhihar, потому что в моём задании необходимо использовать protected, а так я бы с удовольствием вынес всё в public, просто хочу знать, возможно ли решить мою проблему иначе.

Comment: @Harry, а если функция zarplata является функцией класса наследника?

Comment: Делайте геттер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если вам использовать друзей?

```
class employee//сотрудник
{
protected:
    double salary = 0;

    friend void zarplata(employee* k);
};

void zarplata(employee* k)
{
    k->salary = 20;
}

int main() {
    employee x;
    zarplata(&x);
}
```